# Safe way to reassign part of a pointer array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-leaks

I have a code where I am setting up an array of pointers pointing to class objects. Something like this

```
FE **dg = new FE*[ne];
for (int i = 0; i < numEle; i++)
{
    dg[i] = new FE(p, pt_type);
}
```

Now what I want to do is at some other place reassign some of those pointers to a new object with different parameters.

```
dg[1] = new FE(q, pt_type);
```

This is obviously problematic since the old object pointed by dg[1] needs to be deleted. When I do

```
delete dg[1];
dg[1] = new FE(q, pt_type);
```

I get a segfault. When I don't do it, the code runs but there's a memory leak.

Comment: Can you give us a [mcve]?  Your `delete` code block looks correct to me.

Comment: Guess it has to do with what `dg` is really. Yeah I agree with Mr. Oliver!

Comment: Hard to say what's happening without knowing more. Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Why are you using pointers and dynamic allocation? Why not simply a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of `FE` objects (not pointers)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> delete dg[1];
> dg[1] = new FE(q, pt_type);
> ```

If this program segfaults, then it most likely means that `dg[1]` or one of its copies probably has already been previously deleted by some other piece of code. Other possibilities: It is actually the constructor of  `FE` that segfaults. `dg` or one of its copies was already deleted. `ne` is 0 and therefore `dg[1]` is out of bounds.

The solution is to delete each pointer exactly once, no more and no less. A typical way to achieve that easily is to use RAII containers. In case of separate objects, one would use smart pointers and for arrays one would use `std::vector`. Depending on how you use the objects, you might want to use either `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` for all of your dynamic objects.

An example:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<FE>> dg(ne);
```

Now reassignment is trivial:

```
dg[1] = std::make_unique<FE>(q, pt_type);
```

No memory leaks, no segfaults.

---

PS. Reconsider whether it makes sense to dynamically allocate each `FE` object separately as opposed to having an array of `FE` objects directly.